# Getting body from a page as a result of a POST

Tags: jquery, post

I have a page that, when sent a POST request, returns nothing but a token in the body. I'd like to automatically send a POST request from a different page, on page load, with pre-filled values, and then pull the token from the resulting request. Is this doable from JQuery?

I currently just have the following code that builds a form and submits it immediately:

```
function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Yes, what do you have so far?

Comment: I basically have a simple thing that creates a hidden form and calls `form.submit();` at the end. This gets me a generated token like "zHTVUkwWM27_SfVVNEB4uHeM" which I'm looking to pull and use on the original page.

Comment: Please provide code.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'your_post_url',
    data: {
      something: "some value"
    },
    method: 'post'
    success: function(html) {
      console.log(html); // your token
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, though that gives me the error
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load (URL). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`
Since it's on a different domain.

Comment: that's just an issue with your server's headers. read about CORS and google access-control-allow-origin and you'll read lots of interesting wiki pages. It's a topic for a different question though. Lots of stack overflow posts about that already.